# Insertion of a new element in Binary Max Heap

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, heap

Consider the process of inserting an element into a MaxHeap, where the MaxHeap is represented by an array. Suppose we perform a binary search on the path from the new leaf to the root to find the position for the newly inserted element, the number of comparisons performed is:

A) Θ(logn)

B) Θ(loglogn)

C) Θ(n)

D) Θ(nlogn)

=========================================================================

Let's say I took Max Heap as

```
                               100
                              /    \
                            80       90
                            /\       /\
                           50 40    70 60
```

and now say I inserted a new element 250 which will be added at last leaf node as shown below -

```
                                100
                              /    \
                            80       90
                            /\       /\
                           50 40    70 60
                           /
                          250
```

and now by adding 250 max heap property gets violated and I've to call Max heaping which will take O(log n), but my question is now array is not SORTED as you can see from max heap, then how can we apply Binary search at all?

See the array is 100|80|90|50|40|70|60|250 and from leaf to root the path
contain nodes as **100|80|50|250** and this is not a sorted array, So, how we can apply Binary search?

Another Take - Should I've added a new element which will not violate the max heap property say I add new element 30, then array will be sorted in descending order and I can apply Binary search.

So, how should I tackle this in exam?

Comment: Notice that *every path* is sorted.

Comment: the binary heap array is not supposed to be sorted

Comment: "max heaping" does not utilize the binary search. the complexity `O(log n)` is related to the height of "improvized" binary tree - you're gradually moving towards the root by dividing the index by 2 and comparing with the element at that position

Comment: @YvesDaoust How every path is sorted? O mean, when I add new element 250 the path from leaf(250) to root (100) is not sorted.

Comment: @MicroLegions: come on, by appending 250, you destroy the heap property.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So, I shouldn't add new element which violates the heap property! Please, be patient with me, I'm an undergrad.

Comment: @MicroLegions: of course not. You do not insert *before* you have found the proper place.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there is no other way for addition of 1 element. You should ruin heap property and through heapify restore it. It should be synchronized operation for the sake of the outer world, but still..

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin I get that insertion is O(logn) that's combination of O(1) insertion and to call HEAPIFY in O(logn) time.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin: you missed the point. You look for the insertion point *before* inserting anything. You also missed that the question is about the search for the insertion point, not insertion itself. The correct answer is O(Log(Log N)).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'd say original question is about possibility to find "position for the newly inserted element" with binary search at all, and about pure theoretical question: how fast you can do it. But after all, it's after-insert location for the element, not insertion point. Noone inserts into "proper place". General implementation inserts (adds) to tail of heap and evens out heap with several swaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this max-heap:

```
                               100
                              /    \
                            80       90
                            /\       /\
                           50 40    70 60
```

You know that the new element, 250, must be inserted somewhere along the path `[100, 80, 50]`. You know that because in the standard heap insertion method, you add the new item in the first free position in the array and then sift it up the heap. In this case, you'll be adding it at position 7, and the path to the root is 7 -> 3 -> 1 -> 0.

If you apply a binary search to determine where along that path the item will be inserted, you'll discover that it must be before the value 100.

I think the question is designed to test your knowledge of the heap's properties. In a heap of n items, there are log(n) levels. Let's call that value h. The path from the root to an item on the last level will contain h items. Binary search is known to be O(log n). Or, in this case, O(log h). And since h == log(n), the answer is O(log log n).

Comment: Once again thanks a lot, Sir! P.S - I've changed my display name, don't forget about  me in my further quests! @JimMischel :P

Comment: **If you apply a binary search to determine where along that path the item will be inserted, you'll discover that it must be before the value 100.** Sir, how do you say that, I mean, are you applying Binary search on indexes 7 - 3 - 1 - 0 of array? but then again array is not sorted and Binary search can only be applied on sorted array. Hence, how'd you figure 250 will be inserted before 100? I can only say that after applying Max heapify on node 250 then it becomes the root and 100 below it.

Comment: The nodes in the path from root to any particular leaf node are sorted. You could create a binary search implementation that works on the non-contiguous indices of 0, 1, 3. That is, instead of adding or subtracting 1, you move to the child or parent index. The whole point, though, is that *you would not actually use binary search to find the node's position.* The question posed is a hypothetical.

Comment: Got you, Sir. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The heap array is obviously not sorted.

The path is sorted, except for the last node which you want to insert. It's sorted because in a max heap any node is greater or equal than it's children, and since the path is formed of children they will be in decreasing order. The last node we can ignore in this setup since we know it's out of place.

So the question asks you to find the location where the new node is going to be inserted with a binary search on the path. The path has length O(logN). Binary search is O(logN) for N elements. So the complexity will be O(loglogN).

This will not result in a correct heap, it will just tell you the location where to insert the new node. You still have to go along the path to move every node one position deeper in the heap, and that is still O(logN).

Comment: Thanks you so much and **This will not result in a correct heap, it will just tell you the location where to insert the new node. You still have to go along the path to move every node one position deeper in the heap, and that is still O(logN).** You mean, I've to call Max Heapify, right?

Comment: @Geeklovenerds Yes.